# Can this be done in a SQL query? (sort of like a Venn diagram)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table structure like this:

- month (datetime)
- account (int)
- product (int)
- amountPaid (int)

And some example data:

```
month     account product amountPaid 
------------------------------------
1-1-2012  1       1       50 
2-1-2012  1       1       50 
2-1-2012  2       1       150 
2-1-2012  2       2       100
```

What I'd like is a query that can tell me is,

1. For each month, the number of accounts that paid for only product 1.
2. The number of accounts that paid for only product 2.
3. and the number of accounts that paid for both products 1 and 2.

Also, the products that each account pays for can change month to month. For example, one month, an account might pay for only product 1, the next month, both products 1 and 2, and the following month, only product 2.

Can this be done in a SQL query?

The result set might like something like:

```
month     product  count 
------------------------
1-1-2012  1        10 
1-1-2012  2        5   
1-1-2012  1+2      3   
2-1-2012  1        8   
2-1-2012  2        4   
2-1-2012  1+2      2
```

Comment: How many distinct products do you have ?

Comment: Just two - products 1 and 2.

Comment: The true answer: SQL can do most anything with enough programming.  Things just get a lot easier with each release.  You'll probably want to look into a stored procedure to run this type of query, and most likely a cursor will be required to loop through each product.

Comment: with seeing @DavidHodgson's last comment, you should be able to do a simple subquery.

Comment: @ps2goat I've thought about solving this in Python with cursors/pyodbc, but wondered if there was a clever way of doing this in SQL.

Comment: with two products, it should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with a single SQL query, but my solution isn't dynamic. If your products change, you'll have to update the query to add/remove products that you want to display. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/abdaf/6) for working example in SQL Server 2008.

```
with AccPay as (
 select 
  pay_month, 
  account,
  sum(case when product=1 then 1 else 0 end) as prod1_pay,
  sum(case when product=2 then 1 else 0 end) as prod2_pay
 from payments p
 group by
  pay_month,
  account
)
select
 pay_month,
 sum(case when prod1_pay>=1 and prod2_pay=0 then 1 else 0 end) as prod1_only,
 sum(case when prod2_pay>=1 and prod1_pay=0 then 1 else 0 end) as prod2_only,
 sum(case when prod1_pay>=1 and prod2_pay>=1 then 1 else 0 end) as prod1_and_prod2
from AccPay
group by
 pay_month
;
```

**OR**

```
with AccPay as (
 select 
  pay_month, 
  account,
  sum(case when product=1 then 1 else 0 end) as prod1_pay,
  sum(case when product=2 then 1 else 0 end) as prod2_pay
 from payments p
 group by
  pay_month,
  account
)
select
 pay_month,
 '1' as product,
 count(*)  as count
from AccPay
where prod1_pay>=1 and prod2_pay=0
group by 
 pay_month
union all
select
 pay_month,
 '2' as product,
 count(*) as count
from AccPay
where prod2_pay>=1 and prod1_pay=0
group by 
 pay_month
union all
select
 pay_month,
 '1+2' as product,
 count(*)  as count
from AccPay
where prod1_pay>=1 and prod2_pay>=1
group by 
 pay_month

;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only two products there is a simple solution. In this query I assume your table's name is data, and the number three stands for product 1+2.

```
select month, sum ( product ) as products, count ( number ) as number
from (
    select month, product, count ( account ) as number
    from data
    group by month, product
) as t
group by month
```

In mysql there is a function group_concat that does just this ( it returns '1+2' ). In MS Sql, it did'nt exist back in 2000, but maybe it has been introduced since.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Others can feel free to edit, but this is what I've got.

```
with x as (select [month], case when HasProduct1 = 1 and HasProduct2 = 1 then '1+2'
                    when HasProduct1 = 1 then '1'
                    when HasProduct2 = 1 then '2' else null end as "Product"
    from
    (select s1.[month], 
        case when exists(select s2.product 
                     from sales s2 
                      where s2.[month] = s1.[month] and 
                            s2.account = s1.account and 
                            s2.product = 1) then 1 else 0 end as HasProduct1,
        case when exists(select s2.product 
                     from sales s2 
                      where s2.[month] = s1.[month] and 
                            s2.account = s1.account and 
                            s2.product = 2) then 1 else 0 end as HasProduct2
        from sales s1) w
)
select [month], 
       Product, 
       (select count(*) from x x2 where x2.Product = x.Product) "Count"
from x
 group by [month], Product
```